# Corda in Docker OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: docker, docker-compose, corda

When I spin up my docker containers using docker-compose, I get the following error:

```
partyb     | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
partyb     |    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
partyb     |    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:191)
partyb     |    at kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.readBytes(IOStreams.kt:123)
partyb     |    at kotlin.io.ByteStreamsKt.readBytes$default(IOStreams.kt:120)
partyb     |    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.readFully(InternalUtils.kt:122)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.getJarHash(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt:224)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.toCordapp(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt:151)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.loadCordapps(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt:104)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.access$loadCordapps(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt:42)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader$cordapps$2.invoke(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt:54)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader$cordapps$2.invoke(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt:42)
partyb     |    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.JarScanningCordappLoader.getCordapps(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoaderTemplate$cordappSchemas$2.invoke(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt:400)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoaderTemplate$cordappSchemas$2.invoke(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt:386)
partyb     |    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.cordapp.CordappLoaderTemplate.getCordappSchemas(JarScanningCordappLoader.kt)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.<init>(AbstractNode.kt:153)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.<init>(AbstractNode.kt:126)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.<init>(Node.kt:97)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.<init>(Node.kt:96)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.createNode(NodeStartup.kt:170)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup$initialiseAndRun$5.invoke(NodeStartup.kt:162)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup$initialiseAndRun$5.invoke(NodeStartup.kt:117)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupLogging$DefaultImpls.attempt(NodeStartup.kt:450)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.attempt(NodeStartup.kt:117)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.initialiseAndRun(NodeStartup.kt:160)
partyb     |    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartupCli.runProgram(NodeStartup.kt:108)
partyb     |    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapper.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:184)
partyb     |    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapper.call(CordaCliWrapper.kt:152)
partyb     |    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1056)
partyb     |    at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:142)
```

(the error is shown for partyb, but it is the same error for all nodes but the notary). Obviously my CorDapp is too big.

I read some [articles](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker/) on Java in docker container and tried to configure them accordingly, yet unsuccessfully so far.

I tried to access the Java option *UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap* and initialized docker swarm to use the *resources* configuration, but it didn't work out.

Here is the compose file, without any swarm configuration:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  notary:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-4.0:latest
    container_name: notary
    networks:
      - corda
    volumes:
      - ./nodes/notary_node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./nodes/notary/certificates:/opt/corda/certificates
      - ./nodes/notary/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./nodes/notary/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos

  partya:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-4.0:latest
    container_name: partya
    networks:
      - corda
    volumes:
      - ./nodes/partya_node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./nodes/partya/certificates:/opt/corda/certificates
      - ./nodes/partya/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/libs/:/opt/corda/cordapps
      - ./nodes/partya/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos

  partyb:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-4.0:latest
    container_name: partyb
    networks:
      - corda
    volumes:
      - ./nodes/partyb_node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./nodes/partyb/certificates:/opt/corda/certificates
      - ./nodes/partyb/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/libs/:/opt/corda/cordapps
      - ./nodes/partyb/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos

  oracle:
    image: corda/corda-zulu-4.0:latest
    container_name: oracle
    networks:
      - corda
    volumes:
      - ./nodes/oracle_node.conf:/etc/corda/node.conf
      - ./nodes/oracle/certificates:/opt/corda/certificates
      - ./nodes/oracle/network-parameters:/opt/corda/network-parameters
      - ./build/libs/:/opt/corda/cordapps
      - ./nodes/oracle/additional-node-infos:/opt/corda/additional-node-infos

  clientA:
    image: cordaclient:latest
    networks:
      - corda
    container_name: clientA
    environment:
      - USER=XXX
      - PASSWORD=XXX
      - NETWORK_HOST_AND_RPC_ADDRESS=XXX
    depends_on:
      - partya
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"

  clientB:
    image: cordaclient:latest
    networks:
      - corda
    container_name: clientB
    environment:
      - USER=XXX
      - PASSWORD=XXX
      - NETWORK_HOST_AND_RPC_ADDRESS=XXX
    depends_on:
      - partyb
    ports:
      - "8070:8080"

networks:
  corda:
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much memory does your machine have? Corda has become more resources hungry in newer versions. It is entirely possible that your machine does not have enough memory.

Baring that, docker could be restricting the available memory to each node. Increasing that or increasing the heap size in the `node.conf` might help - https://docs.corda.net/head/corda-configuration-file.html#overriding-values-from-node-conf.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! My memory is 8GB and 3840 MB are assigned to docker.  Which parameter in the `node.conf` should I adjust - `transactionCacheSizeMegaBytes`?

Comment: Can I ask how much memory is enough or recommended, if I want to buy a new personal machine for Corda development?